# Can I prevent phone from sleep on a webpage

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, sleep

In app I can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html
but is there a way to keep webpage running and prevent from going to sleep?
It would be nice if it runs at least on android.

Comment: I sure hope not... just think of the abuses...

Comment: It could be asked for, like many other features getUserMedia() and such... There are many usecases where you don't want to go the phone into sleep on a web application. For example if you need the sensor data and want to update the audio every few seconds. When its sleeping you can't do that.

Answer (score 16):

You can use: https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js

> Prevent display sleep and enable wake lock in any Android or iOS web browser.

Note that the library has some reliability/performance issues on some platforms/browsers. Users have found solutions that are listed in the issue comments and pull requests, but they have not been added since the repo owner appears not to be active currently.

It's recommended that you check those pull requests (and/or issues) for potential improvements before using in production.

Comment: did a great job

Answer (score 10):

You can use the **Wake Lock** web API (check support)

https://web.dev/wakelock/

Comment: Now (2021): supported only in Chrome/Edge/Opera, not supported in Firefox/Safari(iOS,MacOS)... no other way that try NoSleep.js with manual bugfixes...

Comment: @rejnok - It's supported in iOS starting from 16.4 (released March 2023). There's a known bug though, that it only works on regular websites, not in "web apps" that are saved to the home screen. As of iOS 17.0.1 (released September 2023) the bug isn't fixed yet - I haven't tested whether it's been fixed in the 5 weeks since the last person said it wasn't working yet. Also, it's not supported in Firefox at all yet.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: do you have a radar link or something for that issue?

Comment: Responding to myself... [this WebKit issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254545) mentions rdar://108573133

Answer (score 7):

**Play fake looped VIDEO or AUDIO on your page**

You can use this a quick example to add a looped video with fake data to your page and prevent mobile device from sleep:

```
// Create the root video element
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.setAttribute('loop', '');
// Add some styles if needed
video.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed;');

// A helper to add sources to video
function addSourceToVideo(element, type, dataURI) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = dataURI;
    source.type = 'video/' + type;
    element.appendChild(source);
}

// A helper to concat base64
var base64 = function(mimeType, base64) {
    return 'data:' + mimeType + ';base64,' + base64;
};

// Add Fake sourced
addSourceToVideo(video,'webm', base64('video/webm', 'GkXfo0AgQoaBAUL3gQFC8oEEQvOBCEKCQAR3ZWJtQoeBAkKFgQIYU4BnQI0VSalmQCgq17FAAw9CQE2AQAZ3aGFtbXlXQUAGd2hhbW15RIlACECPQAAAAAAAFlSua0AxrkAu14EBY8WBAZyBACK1nEADdW5khkAFVl9WUDglhohAA1ZQOIOBAeBABrCBCLqBCB9DtnVAIueBAKNAHIEAAIAwAQCdASoIAAgAAUAmJaQAA3AA/vz0AAA='));
addSourceToVideo(video, 'mp4', base64('video/mp4', 'AAAAHGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28ybXA0MQAAAAhmcmVlAAAAG21kYXQAAAGzABAHAAABthADAowdbb9/AAAC6W1vb3YAAABsbXZoZAAAAAB8JbCAfCWwgAAAA+gAAAAAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAIVdHJhawAAAFx0a2hkAAAAD3wlsIB8JbCAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAAABsW1kaWEAAAAgbWRoZAAAAAB8JbCAfCWwgAAAA+gAAAAAVcQAAAAAAC1oZGxyAAAAAAAAAAB2aWRlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVmlkZW9IYW5kbGVyAAAAAVxtaW5mAAAAFHZtaGQAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAkZGluZgAAABxkcmVmAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMdXJsIAAAAAEAAAEcc3RibAAAALhzdHNkAAAAAAAAAAEAAACobXA0dgAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAgASAAAAEgAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABj//wAAAFJlc2RzAAAAAANEAAEABDwgEQAAAAADDUAAAAAABS0AAAGwAQAAAbWJEwAAAQAAAAEgAMSNiB9FAEQBFGMAAAGyTGF2YzUyLjg3LjQGAQIAAAAYc3R0cwAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAcc3RzYwAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAFHN0c3oAAAAAAAAAEwAAAAEAAAAUc3RjbwAAAAAAAAABAAAALAAAAGB1ZHRhAAAAWG1ldGEAAAAAAAAAIWhkbHIAAAAAAAAAAG1kaXJhcHBsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK2lsc3QAAAAjqXRvbwAAABtkYXRhAAAAAQAAAABMYXZmNTIuNzguMw=='));

// Append the video to where ever you need
document.body.appendChild(video);

// Start playing video after any user interaction.
// NOTE: Running video.play() handler without a user action may be blocked by browser.
var playFn = function() {
    video.play();
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', playFn);
};
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', playFn);
```

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work, so I used NoSleep.js w/ some of the patches in the open PRs and it worked!

Comment: It works... but seems to take a lot of CPU...

Answer (score 6):

In an app there are a couple of ways you can do it, but I guess you mean just in a mobile web page, viewed in any browser via Android. With normal HTML/Javascript/etc., I really, really doubt it.

It actually *may* be possible using Flash (on flash-enabled phones with plugins enabled), though, at least in specific circumstances. I say this because, in a test app without the WAKE_LOCK permission, loading [this swf file](http://www.weebls-stuff.com/flash/5873badgerf9.swf) into a WebView caused the following exception on some devices:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither
>   user ##### nor current process has
>   android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Even if this did work, however, it would run the risk of crashing apps or browsers that did not have the WAKE_LOCK permission. It may be possible due to bad code in the Adobe Flash Player plugin, rather than any intentional functionality.

Comment: A user of my app goes this exception, so maybe she was running flash? Thanks also for the hysterical swf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a WebViewGold/WebView app on Android (while having the actual webpage/web app in such a wrapper), all these mentioned approaches here will not work. But then you can also do set

```
PREVENT_SLEEP = TRUE;
```

in Config.java which should do the trick.

Answer (score -4):

On iOS devices, just refreshing the page in Javascript every few seconds will keep the screen awake. This seems to be the correct strategy, hopefully Android will adopt this in a future version.

Comment: I disagree.  There is no need to make unnecessary HTTP requests to a server, using bandwidth, only to keep a phone from sleeping.  There must be a better way.  Plus, how often do you do this?  What if your timeout occurs after the phone's sleep timeout?