# Tricks to keep phone from sleeping in mobile web browser using JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I know for native mobile applications on Android and iPhone there are easy ways to keep the phone from sleeping, but I am building a mobile web application running in the mobile web browser and would like to explore that possibility.

I have a feeling this isn't possible for security reasons, but I thought maybe someone has come up with a JavaScript trick or something that works on mobile browsers like mobile Safari, Firefox, or Opera?

Comment: I don't know for certain if it's possible. I suspect not. But I'd suggest that, if your app depends on the phone not sleeping, then you're doing it wrong; and you'll have upset users who are annoyed with you for running down their batteries.

Comment: @JohnWatson our app does not depend on the phone not sleeping; however, for a specific part of our app we would prefer to have the phone stay awake.

Comment: Why the f**k was this closed? This is a perfectly sensible question, whether the answer is that it's possible or not, and it's pretty clear.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246576/2441655

Answer (score -2):

My experience with setInterval is that it causes memory leaks and increasing memory usage if used over a significant period of time. Using setTimeout is probably useful here, to keep running a small function every minute. That should keep the phone alive without using up excess memory.

On opening the part of the app that you want to keep open,

```
var id,
    timeout = 600;

id = setTimeout(stayOpen, timeout);

var stayOpen = function () {
  if (stillOnPage) {
    id = setTimeout(stayOpen, timeout);
  }
});
```

When the user leaves the page you should clear the time out

```
clearTimeout(id);
```

EDIT: If this doesn't work then there may be some action you can take within the stayOpen function which triggers something that will keep the phone awake. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Does that actually keep the phone awake? I kind of doubt it...

Comment: I know this doesn't work because our app currently has a set timeout always occuring... the screen still turns off... I was thinking maybe there was some way to simulate touch events? Would that work maybe?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246576/2441655