# How to use the experimental Wake Lock API on Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wakelock

I'm trying to run the experimental Wake Lock API in Chrome 55, but seems I'm missing something.

Despite having set the flag *--enable-experimental-web-platform-features* as suggested @ [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34399016/3431696), I can't get to make it work. Running the [example from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wake-lock/#examples) returns:

```
navigator.getWakeLock("screen").then(function(wakeLock) {
  var request = wakeLock.createRequest();
    setTimeout(function() {
      request.cancel();
    }, 1000);
});
Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getWakeLock is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:11
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note the design document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KbIENP0wgxtSXDQFn9PbHZ_tAKZfR1Y8u4Hst8LpeaA/edit

screen.keepAwake - it's there in chromium, i just checked (chromium-browser --enable-experimental-web-platform-features) that's it's there, but not whether it usefully works.

Comment: also note: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257511

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, there are 3 versions of the Wake Lock API, and Chrome implementation uses the second one.

Comment: Addendum:

It works, it forbids Chrome Android entering background mode, the page keeps being displayed.

I've noticed on a dev version of Chrome 56 Android version that it was working partially, `screen.keepAwake` was not taken into account, i.e it was returning `false` despite having been set to `true` in the code, but was then working correctly when setting the value to `true` into the Chrome Dev Tools console.

Cheers