# Prevent a device from going idle without refreshing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-platform

I have a simple website as seen [here](http://randomcounternet.000webhostapp.com/). It's a cross-platform counter program. It does what I want it to do which it good.

The only thing I want to improve is to prevent the device from going idle or locking when the page is open. I want to do this is a way that does not reset the number.

I've seen some methods but they involve refreshing, which will reset the number on the site.  Is there a way to keep the device from sleeping using CSS or JavaScript?

-Thanks

Comment: I think you should try writing some script which will sets focus on page objects - eventually hidden ones - and combine it together with some time interval. Maybe this way the device will 'see' that the page is still being used and will prevent going to idle?

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended, but yes, it is.

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933555/prevent-android-chrome-from-going-idle-auto-locking-sleeping-phone) for android, but that's right for you.

And here a simple [Javascript library](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js) with what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.