# How can I allow JavaScript to run in the background, in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, notifications

I have some code on a site that periodically checks for information and shows a notification through Firefox's Notification API. If you leave the Firefox app for a while, the notifications will stop.

Is there a way to work around this? There is no problem on the desktop Firefox version, only on Android.

Comment: Looks like Android stops Firefox after some time so it is not JS issue.

Comment: @Stepashka Normally I would think that, but when you open Firefox, the page is still there. It doesn't reload, so it's in memory.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan yes, but it freezes it's processes due to inactivity to save cycles, power etc...

Comment: @PhoenixLogan read more about android application lifecycle. You'll get an idea.

Comment: possible diplucate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106747/can-i-prevent-phone-from-sleep-on-a-webpage